# How can I set the rootUrl to automatically to added to relative urls in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, url, next.js

I have the following:

```
<img src="/productimages/5db35735eb03d2.46088954.jpg" />
```

This works fine locally, but once I build and deploy my Next.js project, then upload a new file to my deployed app without rebuilding then it does not work unless I specify the absolute path like this:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/productimages/5db35735eb03d2.46088954.jpg" />
```

Is there a way to tell Next.js that the relative path should behave as if its the absolute path?

My current workaround is to add `window.location.origin` to all urls.

But this does not work with some of my server rendered paths. I would rather not do that and also not have to rebuild every time I or someone uploads a new image.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good solution by adding the following to next.config.js:

```
env: {
        rootUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://mywebsite.com'
    }
```